# Capifony/capistrano hook after symlink switch into new revision

Tags: deployment, capistrano, capifony

I need to call cli task on my server after capifony switch application onto new revision by symlink.

Its because of clean APC after succesfull deploy.

I know i can call anything before that symlink switch via `after "deploy:finalize_update" do` (i have many tasks there), but this i cannot find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i found it.
Its:

```
after "deploy" do
...your code...
end
```